# Trigger AWS Step Function state machine with S3 event from a different AWS account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-step-functions

Well the title says it all.
What I am trying to achieve:

- Have a Cloudwatch event rule checking for PutObject event in a Bucket from AWS Account X
- When the objects are stored in the S3 bucket, the state machine in AWS Account Y needs to be triggered

But it is not working. As far as I know, buckets are worldwide and not account wide, and accordingly the AWS documentation here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/tutorial-cloudwatch-events-s3.html we should only give the bucket name in the request parameters.

The bucket already contains a policy to give full access to this account where the Step Function state machine is, because the jobs I am running consist in getting data from that bucket, and that works fine. Only the trigger is not working.

My event pattern looks like this:

```
{
  "source": [
        "aws.s3"
      ],
  "detail-type": [
        "AWS API Call via CloudTrail"
      ],
  "detail": {
    "eventSource": [
      "s3.amazonaws.com"
        ],
      "eventName": [
          "PutObject"
        ],
      "requestParameters": {
          "bucketName": [
            "my-bucket-name"
          ]
       }
     }
}
```

Do I need some extra configuration?

**NEW INFO:**

I was forgetting something so I followed this tutorial: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/CloudWatchEvents-CrossAccountEventDelivery.html#WritingRulesThatMatchEventsFromAnotherAccount

- Added Cloudwatch event bus in account Y to give permissions to
  account X
- Modified the Cloudwatch event rule pattern in account Y to add this

> "account": ["account X number"]

- In account X, I created a Cloudwatch event rule with the same pattern
  (matching the other    account) but with a different target: Event
  bus in another AWS    account. And there I put the account Y number.

But for some reason the step function in account Y is not being triggered...

Comment: You should configure your account to receive the events from other accounts first. Have you configured CloudWatch event bus accordingly?  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/CloudWatchEvents-CrossAccountEventDelivery.html#ReceivingEventsFromAnotherAccount

Comment: Yes I already did that. This is why I am not understanding this behavior...